# How to redirect Django button for loop in HTML to specific HTML page for that service?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm working on a django project but got stuck here.
I have a for loop which loops through the data from a model, basically looping in services which are offered and creating buttons for these.
I would like to redirect the button to a specific page for only this service. So basically each service offered gets an own button and if clicked gets redirected to a page for this service only.
As I add the link in an anchor  I don't know how to get it from the for loop in HTML doc.

How should I code this to get the desired result?

models.py

```
class ServiceTypes(models.Model):
    typ = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, blank=False)
    pris = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=0, max_digits=6, null=False, blank=False)
    beskrivning = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def boka_service(request):
    services = ServiceTypes.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'main/boka.html', {'services': list(services)})
```

template file:

```
            {% for r in services %}
            <a href="{% url 'homepage' %}">
            <button class="button_x">
                <p style="margin-top: -60px; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">{{ r.typ }} {{ r.pris }},- kr</p>
                <p>{{ r.beskrivning }}</p>
            </button></a>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can use ```{% if r.condigion %} Your specific button {% endif %}```   within your for loop in template, or you can customize button dynamically - see [Django template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/) for an example.

Comment: Please also include your urls.py structure for better understanding. Need to check if you created a separate link path for services or not and if yes how you created it. This is important to check in order to make dynamic service links.

Comment: @dostogircse171 I added the urls in the question :)

Comment: I can't see the updated urls.py file codes. Can you recheck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `urls.py` add a path like:

```
from myapp.views import detail

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('detail/<str:service_type>', detail, name='detail'),
    ...
]
```

Create a view which manages looking up the detail and rendering your detail template; something like the following in your `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def detail(request, service_type=None):
    service_type = get_object_or_404(ServiceTypes, typ=service_type)
    context = {'service_type': service_type, }
    return render(request, "your_file_that_shows_detail.html", context)
```

Then on your anchor href you can do something like:

```
{% for r in services %}
    <a href="{% url 'detail' r.typ %}">
```

which should pass along that service type to the detail view, and render the page as you want.